# Generate a URL/Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Unfortunately the script below isn't working as intended and I don't know why. The goal is to generate a different URL depending on the earlier selected values.

FYI: There are **3 different base url's** for building the entire url, which is done inside each block of code:

- `:url` (e.g. https://test.com)
- `:internalurl` (e.g. https://internal.test.com)
- `:cpurl` (e.g. https://controlpanel.test.com)

**This is the "logic":**

1. if the `customer_id` is not available, then the first block should be used
2. OR: if the `customer_id` is available AND the `self.tool` is "Website", then the second block should be used
3. OR: if the `customer_id` is available AND the `self.tool` is "ControlPanel", then the third block should be used

**This is the not-working code:**

```
    def url
      unique_id = [self.token, self.created_at.strftime('%d%m%y-%H:%M:%S')].join("&")

      if self.tool.present?           #checks if the order tool is filled out (not necessary as this field is mandatory..)
        if self.customer_id.blank?    #if the customer id is not filled out, then use the following code..
          brandurl = Brand.where(:company => self.brand).pluck(:url)
          brandurl = brandurl.shift.strip
          self.url = brandurl + "/?utm_campaign=" + unique_id + "&utm_source=" + self.channel1 + "&utm_medium=" + self.channel2 + "&utm_content=" + self.bt.gsub(/\s+/, "") + "&utm_term=" + self.campaign.gsub(/\s+/, "")

        elsif self.customer_id.present?  && self.tool == "Website" #if the customer id is filled out and the tool is "Website", then use the following code..
          brandurl = Brand.where(:company => self.brand).pluck(:internalurl)
          brandurl = brandurl.shift.strip
          self.url = brandurl + self.customer_id.to_s + "&utm_campaign=" + unique_id + "&utm_source=" + self.channel1 + "&utm_medium=" + self.channel2 + "&utm_content=" + self.bt.gsub(/\s+/, "") + "&utm_term=" + self.campaign.gsub(/\s+/, "")

        elsif self.customer_id.present? && self.tool == "ControlPanel" #if the customer id is filled out and the tool is "ControlPanel", then use the following code..
          brandurl = Brand.where(:company => self.brand).pluck(:cpurl)
          brandurl = brandurl.shift.strip
          self.url = brandurl + self.customer_id.to_s + "&utm_campaign=" + unique_id + "&utm_source=" + self.channel1 + "&utm_medium=" + self.channel2 + "&utm_content=" + self.bt.gsub(/\s+/, "") + "&utm_term=" + self.campaign.gsub(/\s+/, "")
        end
      end
    end
```

Unfortunately the code does not work. There is no error, it's simply not generating the URL. If I remove the whole if-part, then the link get's generated.

**This is the working code:**

```
    def url
      unique_id = [self.token, self.created_at.strftime('%d%m%y-%H:%M:%S')].join("&")
      brandurl = Brand.where(:company => self.brand).pluck(:url)
      brandurl = brandurl.shift.strip
      self.url = brandurl + "/?utm_campaign=" + unique_id + "&utm_source=" + self.channel1 + "&utm_medium=" + self.channel2 + "&utm_content=" + self.bt.gsub(/\s+/, "") + "&utm_term=" + self.campaign.gsub(/\s+/, "")
    end
```

I have no clue, as the if-clauses should work :/

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: this is inside customer class?

Comment: No this is Inside the model  of the page where the link is placed

Comment: model of the page? what do you mean?

Comment: MVC? :) - what did you mean then?

Comment: try returning self.url at the end of the long method

Comment: that does not work either :/

Comment: What about setting like a default self.url in case none of your if cases applies?

Comment: Nope :/ that does not work.

Comment: Looks like there is a case getting through that doesn't have a tool as "Website" or "ControlPanel".  What's it supposed to be then?

Comment: Proposal is another one but i guess that wont help you. This field is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked a hard question to give a definitive answer to since we can't run the code and we might be missing context that affects how this code executes. But assuming there is nothing outside this method affecting what is going on: it seems likely that `self.tool` is neither "Website" nor "ControlPanel" and as a result none of the code blocks are getting run.

If that isn't the case (and make sure to check the strings carefully) I recommend using the ruby debugger to put a break point above the conditional and then test each element of the condition and see what you're missing.

Comment: I found out that this error only appears when the value of all 3 URLs is the same, like Google.com for :url, :cpurl and :internalurl. As soon as Im entering different values like Google .com .net and .eu the loop as it stands there works... Really strange as the code should not care about the value.